# How to re-enable submit button of file upload after validation error with dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have one additional required input field named 'title' when uploading a file. The user would insert an file and title. If the user did not enter a file or title it will throw an error after hitting submit.

The issue is when I submit a file without the title, get the error, then go back to enter the required title field, I can no longer upload the same file again by clicking "submit."

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="enter post title" autocomplete="off" />
```

**dropzone.js**

```
// Get the template HTML and remove it from the doumenthe template HTML and remove it from the doument
var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
previewNode.id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".container", { // Make the whole body a dropzone
  url: "/images-save", // Set the url
  thumbnailWidth: 80,
  thumbnailHeight: 80,
  parallelUploads: 20,
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  maxFilesize: 255,
  maxFiles: 1,
  autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
  previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
  clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
  acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.jpeg",
});

myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
  // Hookup the start button
  file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function() { myDropzone.enqueueFile(file); };

  while (this.files.length > this.options.maxFiles) {
    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
  }
});

myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
  formData.append('_token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  formData.append("title", $('#title').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events), an "error" callback is available...

```
myDropzone.on("error", function (file, error, xhr) {});
```